# Sending attachment to JIRA througth REST API - Invalid characters

Tags: jira, power-automate

I'm trying to send to JIRA an attachment throught its REST API (POST /rest/api/2/issue/{issueIdOrKey}/attachments). I send this operation from a Power Automate flow.

The JSON object that I'm sending is this:

```
{
  "$content-type": "multipart/form-data",
  "$multipart": [
    {
      "headers": {
        "Content-Disposition": "form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"Certificación.doc\";type=text/plain; charset=utf-8"
      },
      "body": {
        "$content-type": "application/octetstream",
        "$content": "///CONTENT///"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

My problem is that in the JIRA issue I see the previous document with invalid charaters: Certificaci�n.doc

If I try to send the same file throught PostMan, It upload correctly to JIRA.

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I know it’s not ideal but why can you not just remove the special character?

Comment: Thanks @Skin. 

The problem is that I must store the document with its original name. :(